# How do I prevent a Windows.Forms.TabControl from switching tabs under certain circumstances?

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

I have a Windows Forms application with a tab control. When the user clicks on a tab I'd like to do a check (attempt to load the settings into that tab) and if that check comes back false, prevent the switch to the new tab.

What's the cleanest (from a UX perspective) way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TabControl's `Selecting` event and leverage the `Cancel` property:

```
tabControl1.Selecting += tabControl1_Selecting;

private void tabControl1_Selecting(Object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Just embed your logic for the condition(s) in which you refuse to switch, that being what sets `Cancel` to true.